# Eclipse aCute preferences

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-acute

I have installed Eclipse Acute but can't run eclipse any more. The following error `dotnet --version failed to return a version, please specify the correct command path in the preferences`

[image: prefs]

It shows the `open preferences` button and then I get

[image: dotnet]

I can't change the path because of the popup and I can't remove the popup because it's continually calling the `dotnet` executable. The `--version` actually works fine:

[image: dotnet version]

[This issue](https://github.com/eclipse/aCute/issues/115) with Windows 64 bit looks similar but I can't get to the http://download.eclipse.org/acute/snapshots/ in the Eclipse Installer to get hold of the new snapshot.

I tried removing the acute directory but it re-installs and this is now a startup issue.
How can I remove `acute` until this is fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Opening `C:\Eclipse\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.update\Platform.xml` and removing the Acute as a feature allowed Eclipse to start. From there I could manage to navigate to the `Preferences` page and `Browse` to the `dotnet` to directly input a path

[image: dotnet path]

Comment: Can you guarantee this is 100% safe? Could you please link to the documentation you followed or is this just trial and error? What is the advantage compared to [uninstalling via command line as documented](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_director.html)?